# Como llamar a una funcion alert desde php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo la siguiente duda, estoy intentando llamar a una función que contiene un alert desde un echo de php:

```
if($fila["seccion"]=="Escultura"){
      echo '<section class="pic escultura1">';
      echo "<a href='exposiciones/expo1.php?variable1=$seccion&variable2=$nombre'>";
      echo "<img class='agrandar' id='foto' src='$imagen' alt='Logo centro exposición' onmouseover='return animacion($enunciado);'>";
      echo '<h3 id="textostitulos">';
      echo "$nombre";
      echo '</h3></a></section>';

}
```

Quiero llamar en onmouseover a la función animación, pero no se como hacerlo desde php, ya que esa función se encuentra en otro fichero js.

Comment: Si la función está bien definida y desde esa página se ha cargado el fichero .js, sería simplemente llamarla como si estuviera en un HTML normal... `onmouseover='animacion($enunciado);'`. Por supuesto, la función deberá manejar bien el parámetro que le pasas. De todos modos... cosas como `$nombre`, `$imagen`... ¿no son columnas de `$fila[]`?

Comment: La salida de PHP es HTML, así que basta con `echo '<script src="tu_scripts.js"></script>';` para llamar al fichero externo.

Comment: @aeportugal y donde deberia hacer ese echo? entiendo que en tu ejemplo tu_scripts.js seria el documento que contiene mi funcion animacion verdad? gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El echo lo tienes que llamar a nivel de página fuera de la función para llamar-lo desde todas las funciones, aunque también lo puedes incluir dentro del if para incluir-lo solo si se cumple la condición:

La animación la incluyes dentro del tag section con el nombre que hayas escogido para la función de animación , aunque este en otro archivo, y se llamará siempre que incluyas el archivo js en la pagina php...

```
// Aquí se incluye a nivel de página
echo '<script src="tu_scripts.js"></script>';

if($fila["seccion"]=="Escultura"){
  // Aquí se incluye a nivel de código si se cumple la condición del if
  echo '<script src="tu_scripts.js"></script>';
  // Aquí incluyes el onmouseover y llamas a la función animación
  echo '<section class="pic escultura1" onmouseover="animacion()" >';
  echo "<a href='exposiciones/expo1.php?variable1=$seccion&variable2=$nombre'>";
  echo "<img class='agrandar' id='foto' src='$imagen' alt='Logo centro exposición' onmouseover='return animacion($enunciado);'>";
  echo '<h3 id="textostitulos">';
  echo "$nombre";
  echo '</h3></a></section>';        
}
```